# taxonomy_exists always return false even the taxonomie exist

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

Wordpress function `taxonomy_exists` that verifies the existence of taxonomy always returns false.

```
 $tax = taxonomy_exists('categorie-video');
 error_log('verify the existence of taxonomy = ' . json_encode($tax));
```

I used `Simple Taxonomy` plugin to create the taxonomy.

Comment: did you register it with [register_taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)?

Comment: no
is it necessary to register taxonomie even i use simple taxonomie plugin

Comment: yes, it is in fact necessary. You need to 'tell' WP that there is taxonomy called `categorie-video` and 'describe it'

Comment: also i have the post_type_exists return false and the post exist ! should'i register it ?

Comment: yes, you need to register it also

Comment: can you see my code please : this is the link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482470/fail-to-register-new-posttype-and-new-taxonomie

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the place where you are calling the `taxonomy_exists()` function.

Taxonomies are created on `init` hook.
So, calling `taxonomy_exists()` before `init` hook will return false because any taxonomy has not been initialized yet.