# fail to register new posttype and new taxonomie

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

this is my code and i'm in a serios problem with it : any help please.
first i have registered the post type and second i have registered the taxonomie
an always i got invalid taxonomies error

```
add_action('init', 'create_categorie_video_tax');

function create_categorie_video_tax()
{
    register_post_type('video',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'video',
                'singular_name' => 'video'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy(
        'categorie-video',
        'video',
        array(
            'label' => 'categorie-video',
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'video'),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Maybe the slug that you choose in `rewrite` rule is in collision with custom post type name?

Comment: Your post type has slug of `video` and it will be use as base for rewrite, therefore, you can't use `video` as slug for taxonomy rewrite

Comment: the same think ! it still invalid taxonomie error after changing the slug to cathegorie-video.

Comment: from the documontation of wp : the first parammter :$taxonomy
(string) (required) The name of the taxonomy. Name should only contain lowercase letters and the underscore character, and not be more than 32 characters long (database structure restriction).
Default: None